# Gnuplot - minimum from an array

Tags: gnuplot

How to get minimum value from an array:

```
arr = [ 1, 2, 0, 2]
```

I was thinking

```
f_min(a,b) = (a < b) ? a : b
f_mina(arr,n) = do for [ i = 1:n-1] { f_min(arr(i,i+1)) }
```

but the second definition is not working. I also tried `stats` but it does not work on arrays either.

Comment: Problem solved? Question answererd?

Answer (score 0):

```
gnuplot> show version
        G N U P L O T
        Version 5.4 patchlevel 1    last modified 2020-12-01 

        Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2020
        Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

        gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
        faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
        immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

gnuplot> array arr = [ 1, 2, 0, 2]
gnuplot> stats arr using 2  nooutput
gnuplot> print STATS_min
0.0
```

The "columns" of an array for the purposes of both plotting and statistics are interpreted as

```
column(1) = index
column(2) = Array[index]   (real part)
column(3) = Array[index]   (imaginary part, if any)
```

So you want the minimum of column 2.

Comment: Could this be defined as a function?

Comment: Is it possible that `stats` on an array works only in the case when one has `set datafile separator " "`? Because it only works for me in fresh gnuplot session or when i do reset but since at this time i am working with `csv` files, i normally `set datafile separator ","`. Or is there some other business that I am missing

Comment: Ah - good catch.   That is/was a bug.    The `set datafile` properties should be ignored when processing array data.   But they were not (`set datafile columnheaders` was also a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems you cannot use an array as an argument in a function.
Although, you could (mis-)use the `sum` function for defining a minimum-function, check `help sum`. However, it won't work with empty arrays.

To ensure that gnuplot takes the definition of `arr` at the time of calling the function `arrMin`, you have to use a dummy argument `n`.
Nevertheless, function calls like `arrMin(arr1)` and `arrMin(arr2)` don't seem to be possible.

Furthermore, the following should be independent of the setting `datafile separator comma`.

**Script:**

```
reset session

array arr = []   # needs do be defined before the function

arrMin(n) = (_m=NaN, sum[_i=1:|arr|] (arr[_i]<_m || _m!=_m ? _m=arr[_i] : 0 ), _m)

array arr = [7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 6, 5]
print arrMin(0)

array arr = [4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7, 9]
print arrMin(0)
```

**Result:**

```
3
1
```